# What does the regular expression "\(([^)]*)\)" do?

Tags: regex

What does this regular expression do? -

`Regex.Match(file.ToString(), @"\(([^)]*)\)").Groups[1].Value.ToString();`

( = starting paranthesis

) = ending paranthesis

[^)]* = all characters which are not ending paranthesis

What is the need for another () wrapping around the square brackets?

Comment: You should take a look to [regex101](https://regex101.com/) which provides tests and explanation.

Comment: @Delgan: Although sadly not for .Net's flavor of regex. But the flavors it has are quite similar (and the above is the same in several flavors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the need for another () wrapping around the square brackets?

That defines a [*capture group*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx) for the zero or more characters matched by `[^)]*`, so that you can get only the text that matched that part, without the `(` and `)` literal characters around it. E.g., given the input `(foo)`, the overall match is `(foo)` but the capture group contains `foo`.

Comment: In particular, the posted code uses `Groups[1]` to refer back to this particular capture group.